# Elasticsearch which is the better aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to run a an aggregation which is to get the unique ids for a day where the ids in the specific set. So the SQL query will be like

```
SELECT count (DISTICT my_field) FROM my_table WHERE time BETWEEN '2015-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-13 23:59:59' AND my_field IN (value1,value2,value3....value n)
```

I am now using terms aggregation, and counting the number of buckets. But it is resulting in wrong counts and I am getting the bucket count as the number of values for "my_field" I specified in the query string. So is there any better method for doing this ?

By the way, I have over 4k values which need to be checked against for a day. I mean in the where condition.

Comment: Can you post the query you have tried and the results it returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cardinality Aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)   along with [Filter Aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to get what you need. In the filter section of filter aggregation, encode your `where` clause and add the cardinality aggregation to get the count of distinct values of `my_field` field.

Comment: Also can you please show how can I encode the where part ?

Comment: Have done this using cardinality aggregation. Actuallt value aggregation was showing the whole count. not distinct.